# Can't unlock computer once locked; screen stays black

Tags: lock-screen

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on an ordinary laptop.

Once the screen is locked, the trackpad and keyboard don't respond, and so I can't unlock the machine. The screen stays black. However, I know that the OS is still working because I can remotely access Samba shares. The only solution I have found is to press the power button to suspend the machine, wait a few seconds, and then press it again to wake it. This takes me to the password prompt. However, this is a really bad solution because it makes me lose the Bittorrent and Soulseek connections I have sometimes waited hours or days for. How can I fix this?

I should add that I haven't got a screensaver enabled.

Comment: Welcome to AU. The problem you describe is unusual but not unheard. It's seldom directly related to the OS and typically hardware related, either by itself (BIOS/UEFI issues and/or inadequate settings) and/or stemming from certain drivers, namely graphics. So... 1. Update the firmware before anything else; 2. Please |[edit] the question and post hardware specifications (there are literally tens of thousands of "ordinary laptops", it says nothing useful).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The issue seems to have resolved itself. My best guess is that it was disabling automatic lock and re-enabling it that did it.